# How to modify and style a simple form f.input tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form in which I'm asking a user chose between a specific collection of options. My form in my codebase looks like this:

```
= f.label :recognition, "How did you hear about us?", required: false, class: "font required-field"

= f.input :recognition, input_html: { class: "recognitionStyling" }, collection: %w{article blog_post linkedin magazine_ad online_search referral twitter other}, required: false
```

Now sure this works, but I'm wanting to style this a little bit and having problems doing so.

What I have right now looks like this:

[image]

Yet what I am trying to get is something similar to this:

[image]

Is there a specific input that I would need to allow for this to happen? What I tried was to add a class on my input called `recognitionStyling`, which looks like the following, but I don't know if CSS is the way to make this modification.

```
.recognitionStyling{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consolidate the label into the input and add a placeholder within the `input_html`:

```
= f.input :recognition, 
          input_html: { class: "recognitionStyling" }, 
          prompt: "-- SELECT ONE --", 
          collection: %w{article blog_post linkedin magazine_ad online_search referral twitter other}, 
          label: "How did you hear about us?", 
          required: true
```

Comment: So first off I love what you did in that it really tightened up the code, but I wasn't able to get the placeholder to appear.  Any ideas what could be up?

Comment: Oops, the key in `input_html` should be `prompt:` instead of `placeholder:`, which is for text input fields. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: hm.....I'm sill having some troubles getting the placeholder to work.  I'm hoping the error is not on my end, but i'm not sure what else would work.

Comment: Actually, `prompt:` should be outside the `input_html:` hash. Sorry, it's hard to keep track of Simple Form's idiosyncrasies...

Comment: You are the best! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can download bootstrap for that. Then you will have to add the .js and the .css to your assets. For all files added, include them in the top part of your application.js or application.css file as showed here below (so without their extension).

In assets/javascript/application.js :

```
//= require_bootstrap.min
```

In assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
 *= require_bootstrap.min
```

In the views/item/show.html.erb :

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Form control: select</h2>
<p>The form below contains two dropdown menus (select lists):</p>
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
  <%= f.select :recognition, input_html: { class: "form-control" }, collection: %w{article blog_post linkedin magazine_ad online_search referral twitter other}, required: false %>
</div>
```

check this link http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp